# How to restart init container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift

I have a requirement where need to restart only init container after applying changes, And make app container running. This process should be run every day at specific time.
Can any one has any suggestion how to achieve this.

Comment: Is this specifically in the context of a Kubernetes Pod?  Can you [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]?  A Kubernetes init container will run to completion before the main container(s) start at all, and can't be "restarted" _per se_; would running the task as a separate Job make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how initContainers work - you can't restart one independently of the main containers.

Someone already suggested a daily cronJob.

My suggestion to consider is that you create a sidecar container that sleeps for a day, then runs the workload, then sleeps again.

If you ALSO need this to run *before* the main container first runs, duplicate it as an initContainer.  If it's acceptable to have it run in parallel to the main container starting then the sidecar container could well be enough by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a daily cronJob with this process?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).